# Interpreting the solution of the heat equation on the whole line

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Can someone provided some insight on what is meant by "weighted average"?

Allow me to give some exposition.

So given the heat equation on the whole line

$$\begin{cases}
u_{t}-ku_{xx}=0\quad\quad -\infty <x<\infty ,\;t>0\\
u(x,0)=\phi (x)
\end{cases}
$$

we know its solution is given by

$$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S(x-y,\;t)\phi(y)\;dy,$$

where $S(x,t)$ is the heat kernel

$$S(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\;e^{-x^2/4kt}\quad t>0.$$

The heat kernel, as we know it, represents the evolution of temperature for some region in space. In this case, for a 1-D infinite rod.

Now, in Walter A. Strauss' *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*,
Strauss claims that the solution $u(x,t)$ is
"*a kind of weighted average of the initial values around the point $x$.*"

He later justifies this notion by writting the solution as follows

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S(x-y,\;t)\phi(y)\;dy\simeq \sum_t S(x-y_i\;t)\phi(y_i)\Delta y_i $$

and suggests that the solutions $S(x-y_i)$ are weighted by $\phi(y_i)$ .

My interpretation of the solution (in the context of 1-D heat flow in a rod) is that once time starts, the initial temperature distribution $\phi(x)$ spreads throughout the rod and as time goes on, the temperature value at a fixed point $x$ is given/determined by the average value the temperature of nearby points.

Is my intuition on track?

Also, what exactly does Strauss mean when he says $u$ is a "weighted average"?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: It’s probably more along the lines of a superposition of solutions, with the specific superposition determined by the initial conditions. As with many fundamental PDEs, given a set of boundary conditions, we can find a “class” of solutions - in the case of the heat equation, the heat kernel $S$ - that solve the PDE, and the particular solution we get for a problem is really just a combination of solutions from that class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Okay, I'm starting to see it. It's somewhat like weighted averages in Fourier series.

Comment: Yes, precisely what I was thinking. The coefficients are the so-called weights. Another example would be in mechanical vibration problems, where we can use Ritz-Rayleigh approximation and determine the “weights” of the various vibrational eigenmodes based on the boundary condtions.

Answer (score 1):

The literal interpretation of this formula is as follows: The function $S(x-y_1)$ is the normal distribution shifted from $x=0$ to a specific $x$ value $= y_1$. All values of this shifted function along the $x$-axis is then multiplied by all the corresponding values along the $x$-axis of the (unshifted) initial condition function. This number is multiplied by delta $y$. All these numbers are added up. As the area below the normal function is $1$, the resulting sum becomes a weighed average, i.e. the initial condition is weighed by the corresponding values of the normal distribution located at the specific position $x=y_1$. To get the value at another $x$ position, you have to shift the normal function to that new $x$-position and repeat the calculation. The procedure may be described as finding a moving average or as a convolution.

Comment: I do find it more intuitive to think about it as a convolution rather than just a sum of weighted solutions. Thank you for your contribution :)